# Laravel PayPal SDK - Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I integrated the PayPal SDK into my Laravel 5 app. Everything is up to date but suddenly sometimes I am getting the following error while creating a payment:

[PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 137:
- Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NleDc.png)

This error also not occures every time. So I don't know even where to start searching for an solution. My research at the www did not help my further yet. So I hope you guys can help me.

Edit: Just found out that I have only this issue when I am connecting to the live API. On sandbox everything is working fine.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question specifically, but I would recommend checking out this [PayPal PHP library instead](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It is compatible with Composer so you can use it in Laravel very easily, but it's a lot easier to work with than PayPal's SDK.  Even their own tech support prefers it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there has to be a solution. I also already checked PHP / CURL and OpenSSL versions. Sometimes I am getting redirected to PayPal but sometimes I am getting this error message. When I am testing on Sandbox everything is runninng perfectly.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. If someone could come up with a solution would be much appretiated. By the way, appart from your error I'm randomly also getting this `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api-3t.paypal.com`